# Question and Answer Plus Rant in question box. Best Practices?

Tags: discussion

During review I was presented with [How to connect to Bigcommerce webdav via 18.04<-- solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083052/how-to-connect-to-bigcommerce-webdav-via-18-04-solution) At first glance this appears to be just a Question and answer combined and in fact @triplee caught that and [commented accordingly.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1083052/how-to-connect-to-bigcommerce-webdav-via-18-04-solution#comment1780409_1083052) However, the post goes on to rant about the company that they perceive to be the source of the problem that it intends to solve, even going so far as to name names and link to a Linked in account of a "senior vice president of customer success". This strikes me as both unprofessional and possibly libelous. What would be the best practice to follow in a case such as this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest solution would be what I did (and though my moderator diamond definitely helps expedite handling of this type of thing, anyone with close vote privs and edit privs can do these two steps):

(1) Vote to Close because it's not actually a question in its current form.

(2) Edit and Remove the ranty bits but keep the rest of the post which is "decent" intact.  (Also make the images work).

---

Firstly, it was not a question in its current form so closing as "Unclear what you are asking" is the proper course, regardless.

As for the ranting bits, you could've flagged it as not conducive to civil discussion or support, but in this case it is faster for you to just  edit out a huge majority of the remaining text after the actual 'solution' (and save us from having to handle a flag that didn't necessarily need moderator privileges to handle).  Just when you do that edit, make a note that you removed the ranting bits in the edit comment.

If they put the ranting back after you or someone else edits it out, then feel free to flag it for mod attention because they're editing it to return senseless ranting in violation of policies back in.  We'll handle it from there (as we tend to have more 'say' in things like that then the average user).

---

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), in the interim, since I did the removal of the ranting.

Comment: I did VTC and considered both flagging and editing. I was hesitant to flag. Thank you for the clarification as to how you would prefer this kind of thing handled in future.